# How to put two figures in same line and center of paper?

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

I have two figures a and b. I want to put them in the same line with margin and center. I am using two columns format to write the paper but the figure will be one column. I used the bellow code, but two figure are in the wrong location: one is left and one is right of the page. How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \subfigure[a]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{a}%
    \label{fig:a}%
  }%
  \hfill
  \subfigure[b]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.228\textwidth]{b}%
    \label{fig:b}%
  }%  
  \caption{xxx}
  \label{fig:ab}
\end{figure*}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Version**

The `subcaption` package is an alternative to `subfig`. With `\caption{caption one}`... you also could use subcaptions.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-9]
\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image-a}
%\caption{caption one}
\label{fig:A}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.228\textwidth]{example-image-b}
%\caption{caption two}
\label{fig:B}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\caption{xxx}
\label{fig:ab}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[3-10]
\end{document}
```

**2.version ref to your comment**

With `\hspace{}` you could customize the margin between images. In the example `\hspace{0.2cm}` is used.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-9]
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \subfigure[a]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \label{fig:a}%
    }\hspace{0.2cm}%or more
    \subfigure[b]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.228\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \label{fig:b}%
  }%  
  \caption{xxx}
  \label{fig:ab}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want the figure a and figure b near together. They are in big margin in your result

Comment: Ok  then just delete your `\hfill`.-> Second Example added.

Comment: Could we make a small margin to two images? It is so closed together

Comment: Yes you can make a small margin with addding `\hspace{0.2cm}` or more \hspace{1cm} ... . Answer is updated.  -- Please clarify what you mean in your question in future with example code and maybe a image that it shoul look like, that makes it easier. Hope the solution is now okay for you!?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Different try after comments.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
  \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\centering
 \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Caption}\label{a}
\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Caption}\label{b}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

NEW RESULT:[image]

My try:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{minipage}{0.24\textwidth}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
 \caption{a}\label{Fig:Data1}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin {minipage}{0.24\textwidth}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
 \caption{b}\label{Fig:Data2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks but I want two images in mode of one column like setting \begin{figure*}

Comment: I am not getting what you want to achive but nvm

Comment: The figure must be in one column mode. Because my figure is long. You are setting the figure in two column mode

Comment: @user8264 i edit the answer, get a look and tell me if this is what you want to achive

Comment: Btw: Please remove `subfigure` as it is kind outdated and not needed any more.

Comment: @iacopo: You still do not use \begin{figure*} in your code. Let see the other anwser result

Comment: i see the \begin{figure*} in my code. You mean i should remove the \begin{minipage}? Can't get what you want since your explanation are really poor at the moment.